# Proper way to solve function notations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm just starting to use function notation and I'm wondering if I'm solving correctly.

If $f(x) = 4x - 11$, determine

a. $f (1/4)$

$f(x) = 4x - 11$

$f(1/4) = 4 (1/4) - 11$

$f(1/4) = 1 - 11 $

$f(1/4) = -10$

b. $f(-3)=4x-11$

$f(-3)=4(-3)-11$

$f(-3)= -12-11$

$f(-3) = -23$

The equation $C=10n+45$ represents the total cost, C dollars, for a sports banquet , when n people attend.

a. Describe the function in words and then express the function using function notation.

b. Determine C(250) and explain what the result represents.
c(250)=10n+45

c(250)=10(250)+45

c(250)=2545

c. If the total cost of the banquet is C(n) = 4295, find n, the number of people attending the banquet.

4295 = 10n + 45

45+4295=10n+45+45

4340 / 10 90 / 10

434-9= 425

425 x 10 + 45 = 4295

425

Answer (score 2):

All your answers are correct.

However the redaction for the solution of $C(n)=4295$ is not very clear, particularly the line "4340 / 10 90 / 10". Here is how I would do it

$$\begin{array}{l|r}C(n)=4295 & \\ \iff 4295=10n+45 &\quad -45\\ \iff 4250 = 10n & \div 10\\ \iff 425 = n\end{array}$$

Comment: I edited the last question and added in al the questions within the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Madison Ok I edited in consequence.

Answer (score 1):

Just a piece of advice ... if you're going to do algebra, write down your work neatly on a piece of paper. If you want to write down informal calculations, do it on a piece of plywood. That kind of thing belongs on a construction site, not on a math assignment.

[image]

Just one further comment, what you did is correct. By adding $45$ to both sides you make the $45$ a $90$, which is divisible by $10$.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
4295&=&10n + 45\\
4295+45&=&10n + 45+45\\
4340&=&10n + 90\\
\frac{4340}{10}&=&\frac{10n + 90}{10}\\
434&=&n + 9\\
434-9&=&n + 9-9\\
425&=&n\\
n&=&425\\
\end{array}$$
But it is somewhat awkward. It is much cleaner subtracting $45$ from both sides to eliminate the addition on the right hand side.
$$\begin{array}{lll}
4295&=&10n + 45\\
4295-45&=&10n + 45-45\\
4250&=&10n + 0\\
4250&=&10n\\
\frac{4250}{10}&=&\frac{10n}{10}\\
425&=&n\\
n&=&425\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, greatly appreciated!